# How to write a Multi-line RegEx Expression

Tags: c#, .net, html, vb.net, regex

I have a vb.net class that cleans some html before emailing the results.

Here is a sample of some html I need to remove:

```
    <div class="RemoveThis">
      Blah blah blah<br /> 
      Blah blah blah<br /> 
      Blah blah blah<br /> 
      <br /> 
    </div>
```

I am already using RegEx to do most of my work now.
What would the RegEx expression look like to replace the block above with nothing?

I tried the following, but something is wrong:

```
'html has all of my text
html = Regex.Replace(html, "<div.*?class=""RemoveThis"">.*?</div>", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the Singleline option:

```
html = Regex.Replace(html, "<div.*?class=""RemoveThis"">.*?</div>", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Singleline)
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx):

> Singleline: Specifies single-line mode. Changes the meaning of the dot (.) so it matches every character (instead of every character except \n).

PS: Parsing HTML with regular expressions is [discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Your code will fail on something like this:

```
<div class="RemoveMe">
    <div>bla</div>
    <div>bla</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not working. The things I want to remove only have text and <br /> in them.

Comment: Are you sure? I tried it here: http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx and it seems to work fine...

Comment: :( Yes. I am sure. I think there is something different about the .NET version. Or, it could be that my html string has alot more text. 5K atleast.

Comment: Strange. Unfortunately, I don't have Visual Studio available right now (I'm on a Linux machine at university), but I'll test it at home tonight (CET), unless someone else finds the solution earlier.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Singleline
```

The `RegexOptions.Singleline` option changes the meaning of the dot from 'match anything except new line' to 'match anything'.

Also, you should consider using an HTML parser instead of regular expressions if need to parse HTML.